# Weird MySQL Users Been Created (eg. bug115166_10073) and not by me

Tags: mysql, security

Have just been looking at my MySQL user permissions during a security audit and have noticed about 20 MySQL users have been created with random names such as 'bug115166_10073'. They don't have any permissions enabled at all and I'm the only one who moderates the database.

Can anyone think what these might be and where they've come from? Seeing as there are zero permissions assigned to these users I assume they're safe to remove?

Comment: Do you have any applications using the database?

Answer (score 9):

Please remove them right away !!!

Here is why : Anonymous users have access to any database whose first 4 letters are `test`. You can perform lots of CRUD intensive things in a test database. You may also want to rename the test databases to something completely different. Please read these links because I have addressed this issue before in the DBA StackExchange.

- [**Cannot drop anonymous user from mysql.user**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/cannot-drop-anonymous-user-from-mysql-user/4615#4615)
- [**Is this a normal set of MySQL privileges?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/is-this-a-normal-set-of-mysql-privileges/5624#5624)

To confirm the need to do this, please note what [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide says on Page 498 Paragraph 6**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127) in its bulletpoints:

> On Unix, MySQL comes with a mysql_secure_installation script that can
>   perform several helpful security-related operations on your
>   installation. The script has the following capabilities:
>
> - Set a password for the root accounts
> - Remove any remotely accessible root accounts.
> - Remove the anonymous user accounts. This improves security because
>     it prevents the possibility of anyone connecting to the MySQL server
>     as root from a remote host. The results is that anyone who wants to
>     connect as root must first be able to log in on the server host, which
>     provides an additional barrier against attack.
> - Remove the test database (If you remove the anonymous accounts, you
>     might also want to remove the test database to which they have
>     access).

Comment: +1 for teaching me something.  Dear god why on earth would they do this?  (Rhetorical).

Answer (score 3):

Extending from @Pekka's rhetorical question in the comments, check your existing *valid* users' permissions. You probably have an application account that has the `CREATE USER` privilege but not `GRANT`. To prevent this from happening in the future, revoke `CREATE USER` from all but your administrative accounts.